# Rendering a partial view with a model on click within the main layout ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

My problem is fairly simple, and apparently easily solvable prior to Core the situation goes like so:

I have a link which makes a call to a controller action in order to populate data for a model:

```
<a asp-area="Support" asp-action="SelectRequestType" asp-controller="SupportRequest" class="btn btn-primary">Create New Request</a>
```

With this data, I'd then like to render a partial which uses the populated model to populate a modal dialog with some options. I want this to be easily reusable so ideally I would click the button which calls the controller action, and the modal dialog is then rendered on the page with the relevant data.

Currently I've tried returning a PartialView("_SelectRequestType", model) like so, however this doesn't render within the layout/current page.

Is there a way to do this without javascript/ajax? I have seen that previously this was possible with Html.Action however this was removed from ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Hi @Thas,Did my answer help you resolve your issue?If so could you please accept as answer?if not,please follow up to let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you previously can do with `@Html.Action()` or `@Html.RenderAction()`, you can do it better with [View Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0) in ASP.NET Core MVC.

#### Invoke View Component

I will just name the view component "NewSupportRequest". On any view where you want to place the support modal, you can invoke the view component in regular way

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("NewSupportRequest")
```

or in tag-helper way

```
<vc:new-support-request></vc:new-support-request>
```

#### Create View Component

You can put view components anywhere you want in the project. I would just create a folder called "ViewComponents" on the same level where the "Controllers" folder is in the project:

```cs
public class NewSupportRequestViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        // Fetch your options

        // Create the view model
        var vm = new NewSupportRequestViewModel
        {
            Options = New List ...
        };

        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

By default, if you name the view component class xxxViewComponent, xxx would become the name by convention. Or you can use `[ViewComponent(Name = "xxx")]` annotation if you want to be explicit.

Another nice thing with view component is that you can use dependency injection to make anything you want to use available.

#### Create View Component View

The last thing to do is to create the view for that view component. Now here there are some rules you would need to follow by convention:

1. Create *Components* folder under *Views/Shared/Components*. The folder **must** be named *Components*.
2. Create *Views/Shared/Components/NewSupportRequest* folder. This folder **must** match the name of the view component.
3. Create a *Views/Shared/Components/NewSupportRequest/Default.cshtml* view. By default, it's called Default.cshtml.

```
@model ...NewSupportRequestViewModel

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
  data-target="#new-support-request-modal">
    Create New Request
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="new-support-request-modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Create Support Request</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form asp-* method="POST">
                    @foreach (var option in Model.Options)
                    {
                       ...
                    }
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                        Create
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just made things up and coded by hands, but I hope you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,you need to know that the modal would not display by default unless you click the link or button.Secondly,the partial view model should be related to or be the same as the main view model.That is to say,you just need to return each main view and partial view together when the application run.No need to add a link to call extra action to populate model data.

Here is a working demo:

Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

View(Index.cshtml):

```
@model IEnumerable<Test>
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch modal
</a>
<partial name="_SelectRequestType" for="@Model" />
```

Partial View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Test>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

        var model = new List<Test>()
        {
            new Test(){Id=1,Name="aa"},
            new Test(){Id=2,Name="bb"},
            new Test(){Id=3,Name="cc"}
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

If you want this service to be reusable,you could create a common repository like below:

Service:

```
public interface IRepo
{
    List<Test> GetAll();
}
public class Repo : IRepo
{
    public List<Test> GetAll()
    {
        var model = new List<Test>()
        {
            new Test(){Id=1,Name="aa"},
            new Test(){Id=2,Name="bb"},
            new Test(){Id=3,Name="cc"}
        };
        return model;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepo _repo;
    public HomeController(IRepo repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_repo.GetAll());
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped<IRepo, Repo>();
```

> Is there a way to do this without javascript/ajax? I have seen that previously this was possible with Html.Action however this was removed from ASP.NET Core.

If you do not want to use js/ajax to call action and render it as partial in the main view,it seems to be impossible.